# Asciidoctor xml and json prettify

Tags: json, xml, asciidoctor

Is it possible to include json or xml file in AsciiDoctor and prettify it before render?

Comment: You can use [include](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-writers-guide/#listing-and-source-code-blocks) and make a script that will prettify before calling asciidoctor.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible, that capability is not built in.

You could use external formatting tools prior to running Asciidoctor, or you could write your own extension that implements a block macro that performs the desired formatting, either on content embedded within the Asciidoctor source, or a macro that includes files similar to the `include` macro.

With either approach, there is work involved. External tooling means that you can test your approach separately from Asciidoctor processing. Creating your own block macro means that the behaviour is simpler to adopt for authors, since they can directly see that formatting should occur.